# Transponer promedio de filas a columnas mysql

Tags: mysql

Qué tal? Espero que estén bien, soy nuevo en mysql y estoy empezando a realizar consultas, en estos momentos he tratado de resolverlo por mi cuenta pero no lo he conseguido.

- Mi consulta inicial es la siguiente:

> select s.nombre_sitio, month(c.fecha) as mes,
> round(avg(c.loadpower_kw_prom),2) as prom * carga inner join sitio s
> on c.id_sitio = s.id_sitio inner join region r on s.id_region =
> r.id_region where r.id_region = 2 group by s.nombre_sitio,
> month(c.fecha);

- El resultado que me muestra esa consulta es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Lo que deseo es que ese mismo valor de promedio lo pueda tener en meses pero en columnas no en filas, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma, pero no logro obtener el valor del promedio de la primer imagen.

> ```
> select s.nombre_sitio, 
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 1 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS enero,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 2 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS febrero,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 3 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS marzo,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 4 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS abril,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 5 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS mayo,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 6 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS junio,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 7 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS julio,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 8 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS agosto,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 9 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS septiembre,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 10 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS octubre,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 11 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS noviembre,
> avg(CASE WHEN month(c.fecha) = 12 THEN (c.loadpower_kw_prom) ELSE 0 END) AS diciembre
> from carga c
> inner join sitio s 
> on c.id_sitio = s.id_sitio
> inner join region r 
> on s.id_region = r.id_region 
> where r.id_region = 2
> group by s.nombre_sitio;
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Intenta con `ELSE null END`.

Comment: Gracias @Sal, eso solucionó el problema, muy amable.